# Differences in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

I have a question.

This code works:

```
USE [myDB]
GRANT CONNECT TO [user]
```

This other code won't (although its execution is done without errors):

```
DECLARE @nameDB AS VARCHAR (max)= 'myDB'
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @sql = 'USE [' + @nameDB + ']'
PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_sqlexec @sql
GRANT CONNECT TO [user]
```

I need to use the latter (or similar) because I have many databases that need to be in read-only mode for certain user.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @nameDB AS sysname = 'myDB'
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @sql = 'USE [' + @nameDB + ']; GRANT CONNECT TO [user];'
PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_sqlexec @sql
```

Comment: `GO` is not a valid T-SQL statement; it's used only in SQLCMD and SSMS to separate batches. And `sp_sqlexec` is so deprecated it's not even documented anymore -- use just plain `EXEC(@sql)` or `sp_executesql`. Last but not least, escaping a T-SQL name dynamically can and should be done with `QUOTENAME` rather than manually adding brackets (because that will fail if the name contains brackets itself).

Comment: Also adding an explanation about **why** this works would be a huge improvement.

Comment: Remove the `GO` and you should be good, but I agree with @SeanLange

Comment: @scsimon and also not using sp_sqlexec.

Comment: yes I have removed go and now it should be working.

Comment: totally missed that @SeanLange

Comment: As it sits this a poor answer because it is using a deprecated system procedure and has no explanation of why this work. If those were both fixed this would become a great answer.

Comment: And this is a pedantic point, but @nameDB should be typed as sysname.  There is no reason to make it a varchar(max).  I suppose it doesn't hurt anything, but I like typing variables with what they are.